# Different views with same code behind class in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8 mobile application how can we make different views for different resolution with same code behind class ".CS" ? this is possible or not in windows phone ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't require multiple layouts for various screen resolution.You can use Grid layouts and avoid setting height and width explicitly.For other assets like images you will be needing to provide in different resolutions.Please take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx for handling multiple resolutions.With my personal experience,handling multiple resolutions in WP is way simpler.

Comment: but my requirement is i have different layout on different mobile resolution? what can i do?

Comment: What are the resolutions that you are supporting and for which one do you have a different layout?

Comment: let suppose i have one WVGA resolution and on its layout i want only one box and other WXGA resolution and on its layout i want only two box.. what can i do ? i want two views and only one code behind class .this is my requirement